# Problem in UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm required to draw a sequence diagram for a client server **(Web app to TCP server)** architectural application. I have few problems

1. Is it fine to draw diagram to `Web browser -> Server scenario`s ?
2. Can i draw diagram for the `socket` connection ?
3. Can i draw sequence diagram for intermediate processes in the `TCP server` ?

What are the rules that i should obey?

Comment: Difficult to answer without some context.  Maybe you could describe  the scenario(s) in words first?  It'll be easier to answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it fine to draw diagram to Web browser -> Server scenarios ?

Maybe.

> Can i draw diagram for the socket connection ?

Do you mean "can the socket have a lifeline in my sequence diagram"?  Yes, it can.  Sequence diagrams describe verbs by capturing interactions by objects.  You can describe how to create a socket connection in one of them, because "create" is a verb.  The connection itself will be one of the participants.

> Can i draw sequence diagram for intermediate processes in the TCP
>   server ?

Maybe.  Which ones?  Why?

You sound like you keep asking permission.  You can do anything you like.  Whether it's useful is still to be determined.

> What are the rules that i obey on ?

There are no rules, except those built into the diagram.  There are no UML police that will come to get you for breaking imaginary rules.